# ¿Cómo mostrar un número entero en la vista de mi tabla?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Cuando muestro los datos la PK se muestra como decimal, porque así esta declarada, pero quiero que me muestre un entero, como hago para solucionarlo.

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PKMOV) >
      #
    </th>
    <th @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TITULOMOV)>
       TITULO
    </th>
 </thead>
    <tbody> 
       @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
            <tr>
               <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PKMOV)
               </td>
                <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TITULOMOV)
                </td>
          }
     </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba así. La función **Round** se encarga de redondear decimales al entero más cercano.

Round (2.2) devuelve 2

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Round(item.PKMOV))
```

Comment: El Round no existe en el contexto actual, pero veo un MidpointRounding que igual hace redondeo, como lo aplico? se podra?

Comment: Tiene que. Mira, te encontré algo de información [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PKMOV.ToString("0"))
```

Comment: Manda erro al ingresar: Las plantillas solo se pueden usar con expresiones de acceso de campos, acceso de propiedades, índice de matriz de una dimensión o indizador personalizado de un parámetro.